# Computing similarity % in text strings by excluding the identical entries in R

Tags: r, dplyr, cosine-similarity, stringdist, record-linkage

the given R script computes the similarity in % between two names as shown in the visual. Here we have two columns "names1" and "names2" with their respective ids in id1 and id2. My requirement is that when we execute the script, each name in "names1" gets compared with each name in "names2" column, I do not want the same entry i.e. (id1,names1) column to be compared with its identical entry in (id2,names2) column. For Illustration, the first (id1,names1) entry (1,Prabhudev Ramanujam) should get compared with all (id2,names2) but not with the first (id2,names2) entry. Similarly for all pairs. Also, if the formula

```
percent(sapply(names1, function(i)RecordLinkage::levenshteinSim(i,names2)))
```

can be tweaked to produce a similar and faster result here as it slows down on large data, Attaching the snapshot, please help.

```
library(stringdist)
library(RecordLinkage)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
id1    <- 1:8 
names1 <- c("Prabhudev Ramanujam","Deepak Subramaniam","Sangamer 
Mahapatra","SriramKishore Sharma",
        "Deepak Subramaniam","SriramKishore Sharma","Deepak 
Subramaniam","Sangamer Mahapatra")
id2    <- c(1,2,3,4,11,13,9,10)
names2 <- c("Prabhudev Ramanujam","Deepak Subramaniam","Sangamer 
Mahapatra","SriramKishore Sharma",
        "Deepak Subramaniam","Sangamer Mahapatra","SriramKishore 
Sharma","Deepak Subramaniam")
Name_Data <- data.frame(id1,names1,id2,names2)
Percent<- percent(sapply(names1, function(i) 
RecordLinkage::levenshteinSim(i,names2)))
Total_Value <- data.frame(id2,names2,Percent)
```

[image: Snapshot visual]

Comment: When you compare one element with all other values, the output vector would be 56.

Comment: @akrun, thanks for replying here, I think 60, as when your run the Name_Data variable, you see four values are identical, so they should get excluded, resultant vector showing 60 values.

Comment: Perhaps `i1 <- seq_len(nrow(Name_Data));
percent(sapply(i1, function(i) RecordLinkage::levenshteinSim(names1[i], names2[setdiff(i1, i)])))`

Comment: `percent(unlist(lapply(1:length(names1), function(x) levenshteinSim(names1[x], names2[-x]))))` this will be a bit faster

Comment: @erocoar, Thanks for the help, but as per my requirement, I do want to check the similarity based on id's too, in this solution if I change the id somewhere, say last value of "id2", from "10" to "2", that should result in less entries than 56, currently, it is giving 56 entries in all. Kindly suggest.

Comment: @akrun, appreciate your effort here, but please help me to resolve the problem based on the id's here too.

Comment: @AdamShaw  Perhaps `outer` could be faster `percent(outer(names1, names2, FUN= RecordLinkage::levenshteinSim))`  or do a crossjoin `library(data.table); CJ(names1, names2)[, percent(RecordLinkage::levenshteinSim(V1, V2))]`

Comment: @akrun, thanks for a faster solution, but again as per my requirement, kindly suggest an approach which first checks for clone (id1,names1) and (id2,names2) pairs, exludes such pairs while computing and then finally gives a result, according to me, a total of 60 entries I should be getting here. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting the 60 entries.  As per your logic, it can be 56 by excluding the one that you are not comparing

Comment: Are there cases where ID is same but name is different?

Comment: @erocoar, It can be, I'll be very clear here, if every (id1,names1) pair has a common (id2,names2) pair, I want to exclude such entries in % computation, rest every (id1,names1) pair has to be compared with all other  (id2,names2) pairs, also, kindly avoid using if or loops to achieve this, thanks.

Comment: @akrun, kindly check the tables above, names1 and names2 value might be same, but the id1 and id2 values make them different, I do not want clone pairs to be compared, but distinct pairs, that way, if you check here, a total of 60 values will be achieved. Only the first 4 "names1" values are having clone in "names2" column based on id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much faster, but my suggestion would be:

```
percent(unlist(lapply(1:length(names1), function(x) {
  levenshteinSim(names1[x], names2[!(names2==names1[x] & id2==id1[x])])})))
```

Edit:

Alternatively, this might be faster - I guess it varies:

```
as.vector(t(1 - (stringdistmatrix(names1, names2, method = "lv") / 
         outer(nchar(names1), nchar(names2), pmax))))[unlist(lapply(1:length(names1), function(x) !(names2==names1[x] & id2==id1[x])))]
```

Comment: thanks, however, if something can be done to make the script fast, kindly help.

Comment: You can speed it up with `paste(round(unlist(lapply(1:length(names1), function(x) {
  levenshteinSim(names1[x], names2[!(names2t==names1t[x] & id2t==id1t[x])])}))*100, 1), "%", sep="")` rather than calling `percent`. Most of the other computation time comes from calling `levenshteinSim`, where I am not sure of how to speed it up